# Slice assignment to tensorflow variable

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, slice, assign

I am trying to assign values to slice of a variable in tensorflow, but the following error is shown: 'ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables'. Why is this error showing even though I am trying to do slice assignment to a variable. My code is something like this:

```
var1 = var1[startx:endx,starty:endy].assign(tf.ones([endx-startx,endy-starty],dtype=tf.int32))
```

where `var1` is a tensorflow variable.

Comment: Can you show the code that created `var1`? Also please post the output of `print(var1); print(type(var1))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us how exactly `var1` is originally defined? Or at least something that reproduces the exact same error? By creating a proper [MCVE], it will be much easier to answer this question.

Comment: @a_guest It doesn't matter if `var1` was correctly instantiated by a variable node or not -- the slicing op already causes this error.  (Of course there may be more problems outside of the snippet given, as well!)

Comment: Since you are assigning the `assign` op back to `var1` I suspect that you've done this before already and `var1` now holds an assign operation. Note that this assign happens in-place and does not return a new tensor object. So assigning back to the same name doesn't make sense actually.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct; doing any operation to a tf variable does not (always) return a tf variable. So if you're chaining assignments, use explicit control dependencies:

```
v = tf.Variable(...)
with tf.control_dependencies([v[...].assign(...)]):
  return v[...].assign(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once `var1` is sliced it is no longer a variable.

The numpy style slicing notation (`tensor[a:b]`) is just shorthand for the longer tensorflow notation `tf.slice(tensor, a, a+b)` which outputs a new tensor operation on the graph (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice).

The graph you are trying to make looks like (with tensor output types indicated in parentheses):

`Var1` (tf.Variable) -> `tf.slice` (tf.Tensor) tensor -> `tf.assign` (tf.Variable).

Since assign only works on `tf.Variable` objects, it can't work on the output of the slice op.

Comment: Try `tf.Variable([1., 2])[0:1].assign(tf.ones((1,)))`. It's more likely that `var1` has been sliced before and that the shown op is a subsequent slicing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Much appreciated.