# Rewriting function from tensorflow==2.13.0 to 2.2.0: OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ubuntu 20.04

Python 3.8

I'm using a python file (not written by me) with a U-Net and custom Loss functions. The code was written for tensorflow==2.13.0, but my GPU cluster only has tensorflow==2.2.0 (or lower). The available code isn't compatible with this version.
Specifically the 'if' statement in update_state. Can somebody help me rewrite this? I'm not experienced with tf.

```
class Distance(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):



    def __init__(self, name='DistanceMetric', distance='cm', sigma=2.5, data_size=None,
                 validation_size=None, points=None, point=None, percentile=None):
        super(Distance, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.counter = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.int32)
        self.distance = distance
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.percentile = percentile
        if percentile is not None and point is not None:
            assert (type(percentile) == float)
            self.percentile_idx = tf.Variable(tf.cast(tf.round(percentile * validation_size), dtype=tf.int32))
        else:
            self.percentile_idx = None
        self.point = point
        self.points = points
        self.cache = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros([validation_size, points]),
                                 shape=[validation_size, points])
        self.val_size = validation_size

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        n, h, w, p = tf.shape(y_pred)[0], tf.shape(y_pred)[1], tf.shape(y_pred)[2], tf.shape(y_pred)[3]
        y_true = normal_distribution(self.sigma, y_true[:, :, 0], y_true[:, :, 1], h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
        if self.distance == 'cm':
            x1, y1 = cm(y_true, h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
            x2, y2 = cm(y_pred, h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
            d = ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
            d = d[:, :, 0]
        elif self.distance == 'argmax':
            d = (tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(((argmax_2d(y_true) - argmax_2d(y_pred)) ** 2), axis=1),
                         dtype=tf.float32)) ** 0.5

        temp = tf.minimum(self.counter + n, self.val_size)
        if self.counter <= self.val_size:
            self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :])

        self.counter.assign(self.counter + n)

    def result(self):
        if self.percentile_idx is not None:
            temp = tf.sort(self.cache[:self.val_size, self.point], axis=0, direction='ASCENDING')
            return temp[self.percentile_idx]
        elif self.point is not None:
            return tf.reduce_mean(self.cache[:, self.point], axis=0)
        else:
            return tf.reduce_mean(self.cache, axis=None)

    def reset_states(self):
        self.cache.assign(tf.zeros_like(self.cache))
        self.counter.assign(0)
        if self.percentile is not None and self.point is not None:
            self.percentile_idx.assign(tf.cast(self.val_size * self.percentile, dtype=tf.int32))
```

....

```
/trinity/home/r084755/DRF_AI/distal-radius-fractures-x-pa-and-lateral-to-clinic/Code files/LandmarkDetection.py:144 update_state
        if tf.math.less_equal(self.counter, self.val_size):         # Updated from self.counter <= self.val_size:
    /opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:778 __bool__
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    /opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:545 _disallow_bool_casting
        "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    /opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:532 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

I tried creating a function, but then I run into new issues...

```
@tf.function
def myfunc(counter, val_size, cache):
    temp = tf.minimum(counter + n, val_size-1)
    if counter <= val_size:
        return cache[counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-counter), :])
    return cache

self.cache = myfunc(self.counter, self.val_size, self.cache)
self.counter.assign(self.counter + n)


/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/trinity/home/r084755/DRF_AI/distal-radius-fractures-x-pa-and-lateral-to-clinic/Code files/LandmarkDetection.py:158 myfunc  *
    return cache[counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-counter), :])
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1160 assign  **
    raise ValueError("Sliced assignment is only supported for variables")

ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35833133/15019223). I think the problem is that you are in graph mode. It's fast, but Tensors are placeholders for its values, so using them for conditions does not work, as they hold no values initially.

Comment: @mhenning Thanks! I understand the placeholder issue now. Would you please help me apply the solution as well?

'
        temp = tf.minimum(self.counter + n, self.val_size)
        condition = tf.math.less_equal(self.counter, self.val_size)
        self.cache = tf.cond(condition, self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :]), self.cache)
'

would lead to the ValueError: sliced assignment is only supported for variables, wouldn't it?

Comment: I could not reproduce your error and unfortunately don't know what type `cache` is now. It appears that slicing a Variable is not a very good idea. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824843/15019223) help you maybe?